# "cannot find symbol" error in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

```
try{
UIManager.setLookandFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookandFeelmaster());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is the code, in which I am getting the "cannot find symbol" error.

Edit: "master" is the class name

Comment: `getSystemLookandFeelmaster` looks suspicious

Comment: Unrelated: class names should begin with uppercase, per Java convention.

Answer (score 0):

`UIManager` does not have a method called `getSystemLookandFeelmaster`, I believe you mean `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName`

Either your IDE's auto complete should have helped (if you're not using one, you should) and/or a check of the [JavaDocs for `UIManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) would have highlighted the issue and provided a recommended solution - not to mention any number of available examples

Answer (score 0):

`Your code appears to be referring to something that the compiler doesn't understand`. Compile it again. If still it is not solved, then check all the dependent jars are imported correctly. Better to use some IDE(Eclipse/InteliJ etc), it will show you whether your code is correct or not.

Possible suggestion : [What does a "Cannot find symbol" compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean)

Answer (score 0):

There is no UIManager.getSystemLookandFeelmaster under UIManager java documentation.

[UIManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html)

Are you looking for this instead ?

```
try{
UIManager.setLookandFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: "master" is the class name. Sorry, forgot to mention.

Comment: Perhaps you should let us know where the cannot find symbol occurs. Line number to be exact.

Comment: It occurs at the dot(.) between UIManager and getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()

Comment: Your code doesn't have `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()`.

Comment: The dot between UIManager and getSystemLookAndFeelmaster(), where "master" is the class name

Comment: @AdityaSingh You don't understand `getSystemLookAndFeelClassName` is the name of the method, you don't need to inject you own name into it